# Flash Preloader as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, preloader

Is it possible to set total bytes in an as3 preloader? I'm not sure it's correct, but to avoid an infinite loop I've done this.

```
var loadper:Number=0;
var total_bytes:Number = 3484484;
loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loader);

function loader(filename:ProgressEvent) { 
   var loaded_bytes:Number = stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
   _txt.text=String(loadper+"%");
   if(loadper>=100) { 
      preLoader_mc.perct_mc.visible=false;
      loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loader);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just listen out for `Event.COMPLETE` which triggers once the file has fully loaded. Along with a few other tweaks:

```
loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loaderProgress);
loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);

function loaderProgress(event:ProgressEvent) { 
    var percentage:Number = Math.round((stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded / stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal) * 100);
    _txt.text = percentage + "%";
}

function loaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loaderProgress);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);

    preLoader_mc.perct_mc.visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same event there is the information about total bytes.

You can have it as

```
filename.bytesTotal
```

where filename is your event variable as per your code.

By doing

```
filename.bytesLoaded / filename.bytesTotal
```

you have the percent completion. This would never enter an infinite loop.

You can check more detailed information on adobe's documentation and examples [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html).